# C# Conditionally looping through JSON values

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am new to this and apologize if it is a duplicate question. I have tried so many different things at this point I'm not sure the right way to do this.

I am trying to write a function to loop through a `JSON` and get the value of model for certain conditions (ie: `qty != null`, and `sector = 1`, `position = 1`.

I also need to count the number of occurrences for each unique model.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the `JSON` looks like.

```
    [ { "sector": "1", "position": "1", "qty": "1", "model": "SBNHH-1D65C" },
      { "sector": "2", "position": "1", "qty": "1", "model": "" }, 
      { "sector": "3", "position": "1", "qty": "1", "model": "DC6-48-60-18-8F" }, 
      { "sector": "1", "position": "2", "qty": "1", "model": "SBNHH-1D65C" }, 
      { "sector": "2", "position": "2", "qty": "1", "model": "DC6-48-60-18-8F" } ]



public class AntennaItems
{
        public AntennaItems[] root { get; set; }
        public int sector { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
}

string requestBodyString = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

var newJsonString = @"{root:" + requestBodyString + @"}";

List<string> modelList = new List<string>();

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AntennaItems>(newJsonString);

foreach (var elem in jsonObj.root)
{
    modelList.Add(elem.model);
}

return new OkObjectResult($"modelList = {modelList}");
```

Currently I'm getting this response:

```
modelList = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: Could you annotate your model with custom converter and then use `JsonConverter.CanConvert` method?

Comment: What is the use of this line var newJsonString = @"{root:" + requestBodyString + @"}";,

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I'll look into custom converter

Comment: Kiren - Originally I used root as a way to read id/values at the root level when the json was a string. It probably isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd return your `modelList` in interpolation with string name `modelList` and interpolation return you the type of your `modelList` and in your case its a `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`.

So this line

```
return new OkObjectResult($"modelList = {modelList}");
```

Give you

```
modelList = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

So instead of returning like above try to return your `modelList` with anonymous type so you will be able to get actual data containing `modelList` like

```
return new OkObjectResult(new { modelList = modelList});
```

Or Simply

```
return new OkObjectResult(modelList);
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear, please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need root property. I have modified the class little bit and removed the root property from it:

```
        public class AntennaItems
    {
        public int sector { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
    }


    public HttpResponse ParseJson()
    {
        string requestBodyString = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        var newJsonString = @"{root:" + requestBodyString + @"}";

        List<string> modelList = new List<string>();

        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AntennaItems>>(newJsonString);

        foreach (var elem in jsonObj)
        {
            modelList.Add(elem.model);
        }
        return new OkObjectResult($"modelList = {modelList}");
    }
```

You need to deserialize it in List. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I made your changes and removed root, but am still getting the same result. See below.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AntennaItems
    {
        public int sector { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }


        [FunctionName("AntennaSort")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            List<string> modelList = new List<string>();

            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AntennaItems>>(requestBody);

            foreach (var elem in jsonObj)
            {
                modelList.Add(elem.model);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult($"modelList = {modelList}");
        }
```

The result is
modelList = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]